# How do you add already generated ssh keys to linux machine?

Tags: ssh, fedora

I've used Putty on a windows machine to generate a key pair. I now want to add this key to my linux laptop.

Is there a way to place my key into my `.ssh` directory to use when trying to access the relative ssh URL? If I'm not mistaken if the public key has been added to the ring of the place I'm trying to access, so long as I have the private key—regardless of what machine I'm using—I'm able to log in yes?

That being said with linux (in my case Fedora 22), I must have the private keys in the `.ssh/` directory right?

How do I get the private key into that directory, and is that all that's needed?

(I've tried going to the directory of my keys and using `cp <keyname> <directory>` but when trying to get to `.ssh/` I'm unable to—and this is while using `su`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should [copy the private ssh files to .ssh/hostname_id_rsa (or hostname_id_dsa)](https://superuser.com/questions/332510/how-to-transfer-my-ssh-keys-to-another-machine) and then [specify their use in your ~/.ssh/config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client).